# List posts that fall under a particular catgeory in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am working on a blog like project but different and I have recently started learning Django. So, in my app we have categories and tags as well. Now there's an Entry model which has ManyToMany relation with both Category and Tag. Now I am trying to get all the Entries which falls under a particular category, it's a similar feature that we have in blogs.

Following is my Tag and Category Model.

```
class CategoryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):    
    def category_menu(self):
        return self.filter(intopmenu=True)
    def top_catgories(self):
            return self.order_by("views")[:5]    

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    intopmenu = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    objects = CategoryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Entry Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Entry Categories"
        ordering = ["created"]

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

Following is my Entry Model.

```
class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)

    def most_liked(self, num):
        return self.order_by("-likes")[:num]

    def most_views(self, num):
        return self.order_by('-views')[:num]

class Entry(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='entries_images/', null=True)
    image_alt = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    source = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"
        ordering = ["created"]
```

In my urls.py I have the following url to view all entries by that fall under a particular category.

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

Apparently, I don't understand how to write the view to retrieve list of all the entries falling under particular category or tag. Any help will be appreciated. I did refer many blog posts on the web regarding my problem and also searched SO, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778159/unable-to-link-blog-posts-to-specific-category-django) is a similar question I found but that didn't help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
def category(request,category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_slug)
    return render(request,'template_name.html',{'category':category,'posts':category.entry_set.all()})
```

More information on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Yea that works. Thanks a lot and sorry too since I should have looked properly. BTW can you tell how I can order them according to their date of creation once we have got the list of all the posts.

Comment: category.entry_set.all().order_by('field_name') must work